# Bind MongoDB to IPv4, as well as IPv6

Tags: mongodb, configuration, mongodb-3.4

**Mongo v. 3.4**

respective part of config file:

```
#network interfaces

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.15,2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1 (IPs are made up)
```

No matter the format I've used:

- [2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1]
- [2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1%eth1]

I always get:

```
2017-05-17T09:54:54.358 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,192.168.0.15,2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongo/mongod.log" } }
2017-05-17T09:54:54.384 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] getaddrinfo("2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1") failed: Address family for hostname not supported
2017-05-17T09:54:54.385 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): socket is invalid.
2017-05-17T09:54:54.385 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2017-05-17T09:54:54.385 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets
2017-05-17T09:54:54.385 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-05-17T09:54:54.385 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-05-17T09:54:54.385 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-05-17T09:54:54.385 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-05-17T09:54:54.385 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

How do I properly bind Mongo to listen on IPv6 address? Note that this is version 3.4, where net.ipv6 is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Put the ipv6 address in square brackets

Comment: Which is exactly what I've tried, see my question.

Comment: Durrrrrr. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Did you find an answer yet? If not, here is the solution:

IPv6 is disabled by default, you have to enable it for binding on IPv6. The following net-config should work:

```
net:
    ipv6: true
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.15,2001:db8:0:0:0:0:2:1 (IPs are made up)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per MongoDB BOL [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/)
To bind to all `IPv4` addresses, enter `0.0.0.0`.

To bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, enter `0.0.0.0,::` or alternatively, use the [net.bindIpAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIpAll) setting.

**Note:** Before you bind to other ip addresses, consider [enabling access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#checklist-auth) and other security measures listed in [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) to prevent unauthorized access.

**For Example of all IPv4 addresses**

```
#network interfaces

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

**For Example of all IPv4 & IPv6 addresses**

```
    #network interfaces

    net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0,::

Or


    net:
      port: 27017
      bindIpAll: true
```

> **Note:-** `net.bindIp` and `net.bindIpAll` are **mutually exclusive**. That is, you can specify one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

for osx 11.6 and mongo
5.0.3

```
net:
      ipv6: true
      port: 27017
      bindIpAll: true
```